# Jekyll include looking in wrong directory permalink

Tags: css, yaml, jekyll

I have a Jekyll site with some posts and some pages in the root directory.

If I navigate to a page in the root directory, such as localhost:4000/index.html all of the files in the _includes directory load no problem using:

```
{% include head.html %}
```

If I then go to a post using the permalink format as defined in config.yml:

```
permalink: /:categories/:title
localhost:4000/blogpost/first-post
```

The include files are not loaded. Looking in Firebug at the CSS files in the header it gives an error that the file is not found and is looking in the directory:

```
/blogpost/first-post/css/boostrap.min.css
```

If I give the post a permalink in YAML as:

```
permalink: /first-post.html
```

Everything works fine.

How do I set up the include to find the right files in my pages when using permalinks to navigate?

Comment: Does your `head.html` include a `<link>` to `css/bootstrap.min.css`? Change it to `/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Includes` and `assets` are two different things.

`Includes` are partials that are usually stored in `_includes`. If `include anyfile.html` work in index.html, it will work in any other page or post.

`assets` like js, css or images are loaded by html following a path. It's better to use a path relative to the site root. That's why Jekyll calls assets like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

So, if your site is reached at `http://localhost/any/path`, your `_config.yml` look like this :

```
url: http://localhost
baseurl: /any/path
```

And then, no more problems with assets !